# Injecting table cell at end of table

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm completely new to swift and Xcode and everything regarding iOS development. I have a UITableView that populates UITableViewCells, I've been able to graps the fundamentals of that. But what if I wanted to add an extra cell at the bottom upon every visit?

I guess it's a mix of dynamic and static, but I can't find any answers whether this is case as of present date, since information in threads shows discrepancy.

Comment: The table view is only a mirror of your datasource. Want to add a cell? Then add an item at the end of the data source then reload the table view.

Comment: Just update the data source and [reload the table](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata)?  Or just [Insert row at your desired indexPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows)

Comment: For bonus points - scroll the tableview to make the newly added cell visible. No need to reload the whole tableview. If you'd like to see a related example of dynamically loading cells in a tableview I've got an old example available at https://github.com/Abizern/PartialTable

Comment: Im trying to find a way both to manipulate data before, during and after. Before is good, but through every iteration there is some manipulation that seems hard to refactor, after would be most preferred, but I cannot figure out where I implement that code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dynamic table view. For example you have an array with some elements and your table view is displaying them. If you want to add a cell on the bottom, simply add another element to your array and then call `self.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: That was finally what I did. I couldnt figure out where to manipulate the data in the proper way, and ended with a append solution and the final solution only includes a few lines of code and works very well. Thanks for the help.